# Reset button on form not working for javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to reset every input that has been entered on this form when the "reset" button
gets clicked. Below is my code that I tried using, the reset button wont reset anything.
Thank you.

```
    <form id="todoForm">
        <input type="text" id="todoInput" placeholder="Input new note..">
        <input type="text" id="description" placeholder="Input description..">
        <button type="button" id="button" onclick="todoList()">Submit</button>
        <button type="button" id="reset" onclick="resetForm()">Reset</button>
    </form>
    <ol id="todoList">
    </ol>
 
      function todoList() {
    var item = document.getElementById("todoInput").value
    var text = document.createTextNode(item)
    var addItem = document.createElement("li")
    addItem.appendChild(text)
    document.getElementById("todoList").appendChild(addItem)

     var item = document.getElementById("description").value
     var text = document.createTextNode(item)
     var addItem = document.createElement("p")
     addItem.appendChild(text)
     document.getElementById("todoList").appendChild(addItem)
    }

   function resetForm() {
   document.getElementById(todoList).reset();
   }
```

Comment: `<button type='reset'>Reset</button>` you don't need an event handler to reset unless there's more than just that. Just make sure it's inside `<form>` but if it isn't then add `form='todoForm'` to the button.

Comment: +1 to zer00ne's comment, that is the simplest and most correct way to do it, AFAIK. Also `document.getElementById(todoList).reset();` won't work because `todoList` is a function. Not a variable pointing to the form in the DOM. Use `document.getElementById('todoForm').reset();` instead. (unless you are trying to empty the `todoList`)

Answer (score 0):

**Don't add a reset button.**

Assuming this is a todo app users can just delete the todo after creating it. Adding a reset button probably won't provide much value to users, instead it will most likely frustrate ones that click it by mistake.

Comment: More of a comment than an answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Also, I would agree with you if the tasks on this particular todo list were `<input>`s, but they are actually `<p>` and not affected by a reset event.